# System.Net.WebClient unreasonably slow

Tags: c#, .net, performance, http

When using the [System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=VS.100).aspx) method I'm getting an unreasonably slow response time.

When fetching an url using the WebClient class in .NET it takes around 10 sec before I get a response, while the same page is fetched by my browser in under 1 sec.
And this is with data that's 0.5kB or smaller in size.

The request involves POST/GET parameters and a user agent header if perhaps that could cause problems.

I haven't (yet) tried if other ways to download data in .NET gives me the same problems, but I'm suspecting I might get similar results. (I've always had a feeling web requests in .NET are unusually slow...)

What could be the cause of this?

**Edit:** 
I tried doing the exact thing using `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` instead, using the following method, and all requests finish in under 1 sec.

```
public static string DownloadText(string url)
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
}
```

While this (old) method using `System.Net.WebClient` takes 15-30s for each request to finish:

```
public static string DownloadText(string url)
{
       var client = new WebClient();
       byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);
       return client.Encoding.GetString(data);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932541

Answer (score 88):

I had that problem with WebRequest. Try setting Proxy = null;

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Proxy = null;
```

By default WebClient, WebRequest try to determine what proxy to use from IE settings, sometimes it results in like 5 sec delay before the actual request is sent.

This applies to all classes that use WebRequest, including WCF services with HTTP binding.
In general you can use this static code at application startup:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
```

Comment: I got a *huge* speed-boost when I did this. Thanks!

Comment: The second one made huge difference in my case! This is definitely the slowing down "feature" of these WebProxies.

Comment: Had the same issue and this is really improving response time!

Comment: Also can be set in config file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Comment: I noticed the same problem a while back.  I tried reporting the issue to Microsoft but they shrugged it off.

Comment: Thanks! Huge improvement! Has it any negative effect?

Answer (score 2):

Download Wireshark here http://www.wireshark.org/

Capture the network packets and filter the "http" packets.
It should give you the answer right away.

Comment: Nothing strange appears on wireshark, but with trace prints I can see the WebClient.DownloadData() being called, and the GET request not appearing on wireshark until around 10-30s later (depending on the "freeze" time).
It looks like whatever is slowing it down is not the request itself, but something done before the actual GET request.

Comment: It looks like your client was waiting for the timeout of something. Most of the time, it's waiting for the DNS timeout or NetBIOS timeout. You can try filtering out the DNS packet and NetBIOS packets. Alternatively, you can try filtering out by the source IP address. This should tell you what's the last packet your client sent out before the GET reqest.  Perhaps, @Broken Pipe is right.  It may be waiting for the Proxy.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently slow about .NET web requests; that code should be fine. I regularly use `WebClient` and it works very quickly.

How big is the payload in each direction? Silly question maybe, but is it simply bandwidth limitations?

IMO the most likely thing is that your web-site has spun down, and when you hit the URL the web-site is slow to respond. This is then not the fault of the client. It is also possible that DNS is slow for some reason (in which case you could hard-code the IP into your "hosts" file), or that some proxy server in the middle is slow.

If the web-site isn't yours, it is also possible that they are detecting atypical usage and deliberately injecting a delay to annoy scrapers.

I would grab Fiddler (a free, simple web inspector) and look at the timings.

Answer (score 1):

WebClient may be slow on some workstations when Automatic Proxy Settings in checked in the IE settings (Connections tab - LAN Settings).

Answer (score 1):

Setting `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;` or `client.Proxy = null` didn't do anything for me, **using Xamarin on iOS**.

I did two things to fix this:

I wrote a downloadString function which does not use WebRequest and System.Net:

```cs
        public static async Task<string> FnDownloadStringWithoutWebRequest(string url)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Define Headers
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //dynamic json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);
                    return responseContent;
                }
                Logger.DefaultLogger.LogError(LogLevel.NORMAL, "GoogleLoginManager.FnDownloadString", "error fetching string, code: " + response.StatusCode);
                return "";
            }
        }
```

This is however still slow with Managed HttpClient.

So **secondly,** in Visual Studio Community for Mac, right click on your Project in the Solution -> Options -> **set *HttpClient implementation* to NSUrlSession, instead of Managed**.

[Screenshot: Set HttpClient implementation to NSUrlSession instead of Managed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cEkU.png)

Managed is not fully integrated into iOS, doesn't support TLS 1.2, and thus does not support the ATS standards set as default in iOS9+, see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats

With both these changes, string downloads are always very fast (<<1s).
Without both of these changes, on every second or third try, downloadString took over a minute.

---

Just FYI, there's one more thing you could try, though it **shouldn't be necessary anymore**:

```cs
            //var authgoogle = new OAuth2Authenticator(...);
            //authgoogle.Completed...

            if (authgoogle.IsUsingNativeUI)
            {
                // Step 2.1 Creating Login UI 
                // In order to access SFSafariViewController API the cast is neccessary
                SafariServices.SFSafariViewController c = null;
                c = (SafariServices.SFSafariViewController)ui_object;
                PresentViewController(c, true, null);
            }
            else
            {
                PresentViewController(ui_object, true, null);
            }
```

Though in my experience, you probably don't need the SafariController.

Comment: did not help on android unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (also free) to Wireshark is [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using to test?

Try using the default IE install. System.Net.WebClient uses the local IE settings, proxy etc. Maybe that has been mangled?

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for extremely slow WebClient downloads is the destination media to which you are downloading.  If it is a slow device like a USB key, this can massively impact download speed.  To my HDD I could download at 6MB/s, to my USB key, only 700kb/s, even though I can copy files to this USB at 5MB/s from another drive.  wget shows the same behavior.  This is also reported here:

https://superuser.com/questions/413750/why-is-downloading-over-usb-so-slow

So if this is your scenario, an alternative solution is to download to HDD first and then copy files to the slow medium after download completes.