# Read text from webpage without html in c#

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I'm trying to extract the text of an url using `WebClient` in C#.
But the content contains html tags and I only want raw text.
My code is as follows:

```
string webURL = "https://myurl.com";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] rawByteArray = wc.DownloadData(webURL);
string webContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawByteArray);
```

I get the following error with the above code:

> 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

and change my code to:

```
string webURL = "https://myurl.com";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a Header!");
byte[] rawByteArray = wc.DownloadData(webURL);
string webContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawByteArray);
```

The above code has no error, but the result contains html tags. html tags can be removed using `Regex`:

```
var result= Regex.Replace(webContent, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```

But this method is not accurate and does not good performance. Is there a better way to extract just the text without the html tags from an url?

Answer (score 3):

The `Navigate` function doesn't block execution. You need to register for the [`DocumentCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event, then you should be able to grab the contents within that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the way you're using that. First of all you should know you have to use [Web Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Now you can try this code :

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string content = client.DownloadString("https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web+browser+c%23");
```