# How to click a button on a web page that has no id?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

If you navigate to [**this website**](https://www.hudhomestore.com/Listing/PropertySearchResult.aspx?sState=MI), you can see there is an `ExportExcel` button. If I *view source*, I find the button under this format:

```
<td align="right" class="ExportExcel" valign="middle">                                    
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" onClick="openExport('../pages/ListExportToExcel.aspx?zipCode=&city=&county=&sState=MI&fromPrice=0&toPrice=0&fCaseNumber=&bed=0&bath=0&street=&buyerType=0&specialProgram=&Status=0&indoorAmenities=&outdoorAmenities=&housingType=&stories=&parking=&propertyAge=');return false;" >Export to</a>
</td>
```

Following [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271737/how-do-you-click-a-button-in-a-webbrowser-control):

```
WebBrowser MyBrowser = new WebBrowser();
MyBrowser.Navigate("https://www.hudhomestore.com/Listing/PropertySearchResult.aspx?sState=MI");
HtmlElementCollection classButton = MyBrowser.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
    if (element.GetAttribute("ExportExcel") == "button")
        element.InvokeMember("click");
```

I am getting an error as `MyBrowser.Document` is null:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Where am I going wrong? Or is there a better / different way?

**EDIT:**

Based on the s[uggestion by user @DavidR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084130/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-that-has-no-id?noredirect=1#comment71338786_42084130), I have tried the below but `MyBrowser_DocumentCompleted` never gets any hits:

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    WebBrowser MyBrowser = new WebBrowser();

    // ..

    private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyBrowser.Navigate("https://www.hudhomestore.com/Listing/PropertySearchResult.aspx?sState=MI");
    }

    void MyBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection classButton = MyBrowser.Document.All;
        foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
            if (element.GetAttribute("ExportExcel") == "button")
                element.InvokeMember("click");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to wrap your code inside the `webBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event which will resolve this issue.

Comment: @DavidR Thanks. Can you check my edit please?

Comment: Can you set a debug point and check whether the execution stops there?

Comment: @DavidR yes, I debugged using a break point, which I never hit

Answer (score 1):

Get all the `Anchor tags` and find your required `tag` which you want to click. I've made a code, try this out.

```
        HtmlElementCollection links = MyBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if (link.InnerText!=null && link.InnerText.Equals("Export to"))
                link.InvokeMember("Click");
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Adeel Thanks, but I am still not able to "_hit_". `MyBrowser_DocumentCompleted` does not execute.. Did the same whole code work on your machine?

Comment: And I add your code into `mainForm_Load`, `MyBrowser.Document` is still null and pops an error

Comment: I've not created an instance of `WebBrowser` control, I just dragged it on the form, register the events, that's it. You should try it, if it doesn't work, post comment here.
Regards!

Comment: Then what is MyBrowser in your code if it is not an instance of WebBrowser?

Comment: When you drag and drop a control on `WinForm, Visual Studio` automatically creates an instance within designer.cs. I called the control with its default name assigned by the `Visual Studio i.e. webBrowser1`

Comment: Oh, I see! I did not know that. Thanks for the info, I will try it as soon as I get home