# How can i search a hebrew word from a website using c#

Tags: c#, html, if-statement

Im trying to search a Hebrew word in a website using c# but i cant figure it out.
this is my current state code that im trying to work with:

```
var client = new WebClient();
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
        var text = client.DownloadString("http://shchakim.iscool.co.il/default.aspx");

        if (text.Contains("ביטול"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("idk");
        }
```

thanks for any help :)

Comment: Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758283/reading-data-from-a-website-using-c-sharp)

Comment: When you stepped through the code in the debugger what was in `text`, i.e. are you having trouble retrieving the data or searching through it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that WebClient is not using the right encoding when converting the response into a string, you must set the WebClient.Encoding property to the expected encoding from the server for this conversion to happen correctly.

I inspected the response from the server and it's encoded using utf-8, the updated code below reflects this change:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    var text = client.DownloadString("http://shchakim.iscool.co.il/default.aspx");

    // The response from the server doesn't contains the word ביטול, therefore, for demo purposes I changed it for שוחרות which is present in the response.
    if (text.Contains("שוחרות"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("idk");
    }
}
```

Here you can find more information about the WebClient.Encoding property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.encoding?view=netframework-4.7.2

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ran both code samples through JDoodle and got errors. Is the code meant to go within a method?

Comment: Yes, the code must be inside a method, like Main. I tried it myself at jdoodle and I got a "System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure", which probably means they don't allow web request from inside their service (which for security reasons makes sense). If you try it locally in a Windows Forms application it will work. You also need the "using System.Net;" at the top of your .cs file.