# C# WebClient acting slow the first time

Tags: c#, .net, performance, download, webclient

I am using a WebClient to download a string from a website (which just contains plain text, nothing else), so I use the DownloadString method:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string str = wc.DownloadString("http://blah");
```

It works fine, but the problem is that the first time it downloads the string it takes a long time, like 5 seconds. After that it works fast. Why does this happen and how can overcome this problem?

Comment: Is this your web service or some one elses? and does this happen every time you start your client? (even if restart directly when the string is downloaded?)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415443

Comment: Also note that this causes the app to freeze, even when using the `async` version of the method.  How does shit like this get released!?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Setting the `Proxy` property of your `WebClient` object to null should eliminate the delays you're seeing. Alternatively if you've configured your system to use a proxy it can be retrieved with `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy`. The second method should eliminate the delay in either case.

Comment: Neither `webClient.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` nor `WebRequest.DefaultProxy` fix the problem, the delay still occurs.  Setting it to `null` or `GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy()` _does_ work... but then the app can no longer be used on connections that require a proxy!  Is there really no solution!?

Answer (score 6):

I noticed the same thing. DotTrace shows it's spending the majority of its time enumerating proxy options:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Well, the first time it needs to do a DNS lookup and connect to the host - after that, within the same process it may well be reusing the same connection. For the very first request to *anywhere*, it may well *also* be trying to detect proxy settings etc.

If you want to see what's really happening at the network level to make it slow, I suggest you grab [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) and monitor the traffic with that.