# SOAP web service consumed with HttpWebRequest taking a long time for first request

Tags: c#, asp.net

Secure SOAP web service consumed with `HttpWebRequest` taking 30-40 seconds for the first request. Subsequent requests are fast (1-2 seconds).

Nothing wrong on the webservice side as it's responding within same time for all the 
requests.
Log shows request takes time to reach to the web service and I am not sure what is causing this delay.

What can be the issue?

Could the web service requiring client certificate to authenticate be causing this delay?

Comment: Can you please check setting on IIS configure `keepalive = true` - which may improve the performance because when you request first time app pool need to start.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Try set `Proxy` property of `HttpWebRequest` to null.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the IIS, app pool is not recycling.

Comment: Yes, I am behind the proxy and set the proxy server address in the request so I think it should take that as proxy and should not look for any default proxy address

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932541/c-sharp-webclient-acting-slow-the-first-time and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415443/system-net-webclient-unreasonably-slow. It's for `WebClient` but maybe can fit to your case.